# How to use regex to match one or two words

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I want to extract the ratings after the section in the following text. It could be either one word or two words. For example "Partly Satisfactory", "Satisfactory". Which regex pattern should I use? I'm using word vba

```
Section 1
Partly Satisfactory 
Some paragraphs inserted here

Section 2
Satisfactory
Another paragraphs inserted here

Section 3
Partly Unsuccessful
Another paragraphs inserted here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern can be e.g.:  `(Section \d+[\r\n])(\w+(?: \w+)?)`.

The first capturing group catches the first row (*Section*, number and newline).

The second capturing group catches the rating (one or two words)
and this is what you actually need.

Below you have an example script, checked (used as a macro) on a Word document.

```
Sub Re()
  Dim pattern As String: pattern = "(Section \d+[\r\n])(\w+(?: \w+)?)"
  Dim regEx As New RegExp
  Dim src As String
  Dim ret As String
  Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
  Dim objMatch As Match

  ActiveDocument.Range.Select
  src = ActiveDocument.Range.Text
  Selection.StartOf

  With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .pattern = pattern
  End With
  If (regEx.Test(src)) Then
    Set colMatches = regEx.Execute(src)
    ret = "Matches " & colMatches.Count & ": "
    For Each objMatch In colMatches
      ret = ret & vbCrLf & objMatch.SubMatches(1)
    Next
  Else
    ret = "Matching Failed"
  End If
  MsgBox ret, vbOKOnly, "Result"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what I'm looking for!